# Undefined variable: gridColumns in karik gridview:yii2

Tags: yii2

I'm trying to use kartik gridview and got the following error. -

```
Undefined variable: gridColumns
```

I've checked  - [Yii2: Kartik Gridview sum of a column in footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29183729/yii2-kartik-gridview-sum-of-a-column-in-footer). But didn't find the issue in my code.

Code of index.php -

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => $gridColumns,
        'showPageSummary' => true,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'kartik\grid\SerialColumn'],
            [
                'attribute'=>'s_period',
                'filter'=>ArrayHelper::map(Salary::find()->asArray()->all(), 's_period', 's_period'),
            ],
            's_empid',
            's_empname',
            [
                'attribute'=>'s_epf',
                'pageSummary'=>true
            ],


            //['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

Comment: Are you define $gridColumns? what' this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you assign manually the columns you don't need a var  iwth columns specification so remove it

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        //'columns' => $gridColumns,
        'showPageSummary' => true,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'kartik\grid\SerialColumn'],
            [
                'attribute'=>'s_period',
                'filter'=>ArrayHelper::map(Salary::find()->asArray()->all(), 's_period', 's_period'),
            ],
            's_empid',
            's_empname',
            [
                'attribute'=>'s_epf',
                'pageSummary'=>true
            ],


            //['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

Comment: The Code is running fine without $gridColumn.